# Passing in config values to a method using SOLID principles

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have an email helper class that has a method that sends email:

```
private static class EmailHelper
{
    public static void SendEmail(string from, string to, string subject, string message)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
        var client = new SmtpClient("my.smpthost.com"); //this will be moved to config.
        client.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

My smtp host string will be placed in my config file. Question is what's the recommended way to pass the smtp host to this method? Should I have a constructor in this class that takes in the smtp string? Or, should I pass the smtp as a 5th parameter? Or should this method directly read from the config?

(I realize that there may be several different ways to do this, but I am trying to understand the recommended approach, or at least approaches that are NOT recommended, keeping in mind the SOLID principles.)

Comment: This might be a better question for [programmers.se]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the SOLID principles I would design the code differently. Currently all code using the EmailHelper will depend on this exact implementation.

I would create two interfaces. Something like this:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    string GetConfigurationValue(string key);
}

public interface IEmailHelper
{
    void SendEmail(string from, string to, string subject, string message);
}
```

Then you can implement the EmailHelper like this:

```
public class EmailHelper : IEmailHelper
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public EmailHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void SendEmail(string from, string to, string subject, string message)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
        var client = new SmtpClient(_configuration.GetConfigurationValue("smpthost")); //this will be moved to config.
        client.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

Now you can swap out the implementation for both the email service and the configurations. I believe this follows the SOLID principles. This is very useful for unit testing as well.